# v-on:click not working in a child component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

First thing first I'm new to vue.js.

what I'm trying to do when the user click on the expander anchor tag in the item-preview component the item-details will display and the item-preview will be hide. Now the problem occurs when the item-preview displayed and i'm trying to toggle it by clicking its own expander anchor tag. I do not whats wrong with this.

Here is my HTML templates.

```
    <script type="text/x-template" id="grid">
    <div class="model item" v-for="entry in data">
        <item-preview v-bind:entry="entry" v-if="entry.hide == 0">
        </item-preview>
        <item-details v-bind:entry="entry" v-if="entry.hide == 1">
        </item-details>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="item-preview">
        <header class="preview">
            <a class="expander" tabindex="-1" v-on:click="toggle(entry)"></a>
            <span class="name rds_markup">
                {{ entry.name }}
            </span>
        </header>
</script>


<script type="text/x-template" id="item-details">
    <div class="edit details">
        <section class="edit" tabindex="-1">
            <form action="#">
                <fieldset class="item name">
                    <a class="expander"  v-on:click="toggle(entry)"></a>
                    {{ entry.name }}
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
</script>
```

And here how I called the grid component on my view.

```
<grid
    :data="packages">
</grid>
```

And for my Vue implementation

```
var itemPreview = Vue.component('item-preview',{
    'template':"#item-preview",
    'props':{
        entry:Object
    },
    methods:{
        toggle:function(entry){
            entry.hide = !!entry.hide;
            return true;
        }
    }
});

var itemDetails = Vue.component('item-details',{
    'template':"#item-details",
    'props':{
        entry:Object
    },
    methods:{
        toggle:function(entry){
            entry.hide = !!entry.hide;
            return true;
        }
    }
});

var grid = Vue.component('grid',{
    'template':"#grid",
    'props':{
        data:Array,
    },
    components:{
        'item-preview': itemPreview,
        'item-details': itemDetails
    },
    methods:{
        toggle:function(entry){
            entry.hide = !!entry.hide;
            return true;
        }
    }
});




var vm = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        message:'Hello',
        packages:{}
    },

    ready:function(){
        this.fetchPackages();
    },

    methods:{
        fetchPackages:function(){
            this.$http.get(url1,function( response ){
                this.$set('packages',response);
            });
        },

    }

});
```

Comment: ` entry.hide = !!entry.hide;` there should be only one `!`

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. It took me 30minutes to figure out what is wrong with this code.

What I did to fix this is instead of  `entry.hide = !!entry.hide;` I use `entry.hide = true` in item-preview component and in the item-details `entry.hide = false`. this fix my issue.

Comment: `entry.hide = !!entry.hide;` doesn't do anything... `entry.hide = !entry.hide` would toggle the value.